# How can I effectively display a progress bar while my app pastes a file? Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on a small file manager for school and I am trying to get it to display the progress while pasting the file into the new location. How can I get it to do this? I understand how to set progress in a dialog, but what would you use for the file? I currently have it so the max of the progress bar is the number of files the user is trying to paste, but that only works well when the user is pasting multiple files and not just one. Is there a way to update the number of the progress bar with the number of bytes pasted or something similar?

### Code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mClipboard.size(); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            // Copy, or cut, each file or directory into the destination directory
            final File newFile = copy(getFile(i), dest, false);
            scanImage(newFile, context);
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Update the adapter and increment the progress dialog
                    if (newFile != null) adapter.add(newFile);
                    // Increment the progress dialog
                    dialog.setProgress(index);
                }
            });
        }

        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Remove paste option from action bar
                context.invalidateOptionsMenu();
                // Clear the clipboard
                clear();
                // Close the dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are relatively new to android, there is a class called the async task. You can use i to run any background operation. And displaying a dialog while its running in the background is as simple as:

```
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
    return null;
    }
}
```

Then write an async task to update progress..

```
private class DownloadZipFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Your background task code here.
        publishProgress("" + progress);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {        
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. I am new to Android, but I get that, the thing I don't get is how/what should I use to increment the progress? Should I try to find the current percentage of bytes that have been written to the new directory or do what?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use async task to paste the file in the background. 
Here is the good code exaple for you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Android dowumenation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html